# How to split screen in Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: multiple-monitors, desktop-environments

I have two monitors connected with one CPU. The operating system installed is Ubuntu desktop. Both screen is duplicate, I am unable to split it. While if I am connecting windows machine it successfully splitting screen.

Please help, how to troubleshoot and resolve the issue?

Comment: Settings > Devices > Displays... Nothing to troubleshoot, it's a matter of setting your preferences.

Comment: I already check, but not getting option there.any driver required for this?

Comment: You may need to install Nvidia drivers for Nvidia, obviously. Other than that no, you don't. But both monitors are working hen you also don't. And the option for extended desktop and mirror - your current setting - are also there an they're BIG buttons.

Comment: I check driver, drivers are installed. But it is not working. I also installed Ubuntu mate. Both monitors are showing same display.